# Form Validation Call Back Function Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here Is My COde I m checking username is already exist or not in datbase
 when i validate and submit the form duplicate entry entered in database i want that if already exist it show validation error

My Controller

```
public function index()
{
     if($this->input->post('submit'))   {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'User Name', 'callback_checkuser');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('role', 'Role', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'trim|required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE)
           {
               $user['u_name']  =   $this->input->post('name');
               $user['role']    =   $this->input->post('role');
               $user['password']=   md5($this->input->post('pass'));
               $u_id =  $this->custom_model->add_user($user);
               if($u_id){
                  $data['msg']  =   'Successfully Created!!!!';
               }
           }
        }
     $this->load->template('add_user', $data);
}

function checkuser($name) {
    if($this->custom_model->check_name($name) == false) {
        false;
    }else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkuser', 'This user already exist');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is My Model

```
public function check_name($name) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_name='".$name."' ";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $res = $query->row_array();
        if (is_array($res) && count($res) > 0){
            return $res;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: NB: in `checkuser` you have `false` without preceding `return`.

Comment: i added return but still record add in databse

Comment: Within the validation function, your true/false logic is totally backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `return` statement missing in the function *checkuser*, but more importantly, you should invert the value you return. According to the [example in the docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks), when you set a validation message because of a validation error, you should return `false`, and return `true` when the validation passes.

So add a `return`, and change the boolean values. BTW, you don't really need an `else` clause and the word *"exist"* needs an additional *"s"*:

```
function checkuser($name) {
    if ($this->custom_model->check_name($name) == false) {
        return true; // the user does not yet exist, so all is OK
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_message('checkuser', 'This user already exists');
    return false; // this is a duplicate user name: not OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[users.u_name]');// trim and required added too
```

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference).